# ip table rules for allow memcache connections

Tags: iptables

What do the following rules mean? The rules were put in by a sysadmin and seem to be working, but I think there is some redundancy in them. My goal is to allow connections on port 11211. This is on a memcache server that is connected to from various web servers.

memcache server internal ip: 10.181.16.192

memcache server external ip: 166.78.9.65

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat Sep 27 14:15:42 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [198925:147304500]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh 
-A INPUT -s 10.181.16.192/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 10.181.26.42/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 10.181.16.192/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment "SSH" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "HTTPS" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m comment --comment "HTTP" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 67.222.16.43/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m comment --comment "MySQL" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m comment --comment "MySQL" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 10.181.16.33/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -m comment --comment "memcached" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 166.78.10.99/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -m comment --comment "memcached" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 174.143.23.0/25 -m comment --comment "Rackspace monitoring" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 174.143.23.0/25 -m comment --comment "Rackspace monitoring" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 50.56.142.128/26 -m comment --comment "Rackspace monitoring" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 180.150.149.64/26 -m comment --comment "Rackspace monitoring" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 69.20.52.192/26 -m comment --comment "Rackspace monitoring" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 78.136.44.0/26 -m comment --comment "Rackspace monitoring" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 50.57.61.0/26 -m comment --comment "Rackspace monitoring" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 173.241.208.122/32 -m comment --comment "developer" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 204.232.241.45/32 -m comment --comment "developer" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 184.106.252.94/32 -m comment --comment "developer" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -s 178.219.251.50/32 -m comment --comment "developer" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "localhost" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -m comment --comment "ping" -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 27 14:15:42 2014
```

Comment: I still don't think I have given you all the information. How do I get you the complete setup?

Answer (score 1):

The only duplicate definition is this:

-A INPUT -s 10.181.16.192/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT

The same definition is also in the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT chain, which is used after the normal INPUT chain.

This is assuming that `eth1` is for internal network and `eth0` is the outside network.

There is one issue though: The misconfiguration of ICMP firewalling. Only Ping packets are passed through, which means that Path MTU discovery doesn't work correctly, and it might cause some issues. Also `Destination Unreachable` packets should be allowed.

Comment: Also if I spin up another web server with a different IP...it is able to communicate with the memcache server...Based on my very limited understanding of the firewall; I would think it would be blocked.

Comment: Depends on if it connects to the internal network or external and internal networks.